# link_to with nested routes within loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm struggling with this, seems like it should be simple - I just can't see why it won't work.

I have the following loop in my payments view, I'm wanting to link_to delete and edit.
I'm passing in the @bill object and the past_payment object.

I'm getting this error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :bill_id=>11, :controller=>"payments", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

I can't see why I can't get an :id from past_payment. I've tried using past_payment.id and have made sure it exists on the object by printing it as part of the table. Seems to work if I statically put in an id.

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>Payment for : <%=  @bill.vendor.full_vendor %></h4>
    <p>Amount Owing: <%= humanized_money_with_symbol @bill.owing %></p>
    <p>Due: <%=  @bill.due_date.to_formatted_s(:rfc822) %> </p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>Payment Options</h4>
    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
      <tr>
        <td><%=image_tag("40px_BPAY_2012_PORT_BLUE.png", alt: "BPay_Image")%></td>
        <td><p>biller code:</br><%=  @bill.vendor.bpay_biller_code %></p></td>
        <td><p>ref number:</br><%=  @bill.vendor.bpay_ref %></p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row col-md-12">
  <h4>This Payment</h4>
</div>

  <%= form_for(@payment, url: :bill_payments, html: { method: "post", class: "form-horizontal", role: "form" } ) do |payment| %>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <%= payment.label :amount, class: "control-label sr-only" %>
      <%= payment.text_field :amount, data: { role: 'money', aSign: '$'}, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Amount Paid"  %>

      <%= payment.label :receipt_number, class: "control-label sr-only" %>
      <%= payment.text_field :receipt_number, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Receipt #" %>

      <%= payment.label :notes, class: "control-label sr-only" %>
      <%= payment.text_area :notes, class: "form-control", rows: "1", placeholder: "Notes"  %>

      <div class="form-inline">
      <%= payment.label :payment_date, class: "control-label sr-only" %>
      <%= payment.date_select :payment_date, { order: [ :day, :month, :year ],
        start_year: 2014,
        end_year:2020 },
        class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>

  <%= payment.submit "Pay", class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <% end %>


</br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h4>Previous Payments</h4>
      <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
        <tr>
          <th>Amount Paid</th>
          <th>Receipt #</th>
          <th>Date Paid</th>
          <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
      </tr>
      <% @bill.payments.each do |past_payment| %>
        <tr>
          <td><p><%= humanized_money_with_symbol past_payment.amount %></p></td>
          <td><p><%=  past_payment.receipt_number %></p></td>
          <td>
            <% if not past_payment.payment_date == nil %>
              <p><%=  past_payment.payment_date.to_formatted_s(:rfc822) %></p>
            <% end %>
            </td>
 -->        <td>
              <%= link_to "Edit", edit_bill_payment_path(@bill, past_payment), method: :patch %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= link_to "Delete", bill_payment_path(@bill, past_payment), method: :delete,
 -->               data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
            </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
      </table>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Controller Code

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!


  def new
    @bill=Bill.find(params[:bill_id])
    @payment=@bill.payments.new
  end

  def edit
    @bill=Bill.find(params[:bill_id])
    @payment=@bill.payments.find(:id)
  end

  def update
    @bill=Bill.find(params[:bill_id])
    if @bill.payments(payment_params).update
      flash[:success] = "This payment has been updated"
      redirect_to new_bill_payment_url(params[:bill_id])
    else
      flash[:error] = "There has been a problem updateing this payment"
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  def create
      @bill=Bill.find(params[:bill_id])
     if @bill.payments.save
      flash[:success] = "This payment has been registered"
      redirect_to new_bill_payment_url(params[:bill_id])
    else
      flash[:error] = "There has been a problem with this payment"
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @bill=Bill.find(params[:bill_id])

    if @bill.payments.find(params[:id]).destroy
      flash[:success] = "This payment has been removed"
      redirect_to new_bill_payment_url(params[:bill_id])
    else
      flash[:error] = "There has been a problem removing this payment"
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end


private

  def payment_params
    params.require(:payment).permit(:id, :bill_id,:receipt_number, :notes, :amount,
                                                :payment_date)
  end

end
```

Route Snippet

```
resources :bills do
  resources :payments, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy]
end
```

Bill Model

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :vendor
  has_many :payments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments, allow_destroy: true

  validates :vendor_id, :amount, :due_date, :bill_type, presence: true
  validate :over_payment

  monetize :amount_cents
  monetize :gst_cents
  monetize :owing_cents

  def owing_cents
    self.amount_cents - self.payments.sum(:amount_cents)
  end

  def gst_cents
    self.amount_cents/11
  end

private
  def over_payment
    if self.payments.sum(:amount_cents) > owing_cents
      errors.add(:amount, "Over payment of a bill not allowed
        add interest or penitalties as a negitive payment first")
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you give the snippets from your route ?

Comment: Please share the controller code where @bill is being initialized.

Comment: Is this error thrown from `new` action?

Comment: thanks @blelump I've added the full view. Yes it's driven from the `new` action

Comment: Have you checked your form? Looks like you might be missing the bill variable as well: <%= form_for( [@bill, @payment], ...

Comment: The form works. The new action from the controller pushes in @bill and @payment. If I statically put in a payment ID `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_bill_payment_path(@bill, 5), method: :patch %>` everything comes up fine.Including the table that uses past_payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following resolved my issue.

```
<td>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_bill_payment_path(@bill, id: "#{past_payment.id}"), method: :patch %>
</td>
<td>
  <%= link_to "Delete", bill_payment_path(@bill, id: "#{past_payment.id}"), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
</td>
```

I'm not sure if this is best practice or why using the past_payment object didn't work. Need to do a little more research I think.

Thanks to those who responded.

Answer (score 1):

In actions you use `@bill=Bill.find(params[:bill_id])` everywhere, but `@bill` has an `:id`, not `:bill_id`. This is the problem. What you really want is to use `@bill=Bill.find(params[:id])`.

The link you use:  `<%= link_to "Pay", new_bill_payment_path(bill) %>` gives you  `:id=>nil`, because there is no bill object, but @bill, hence link most likely should be `<%= link_to "Pay", new_bill_payment_path(@bill) %>`

Comment: Thanks Andrey - The new action in the payments controler is called from: `      <%= link_to "Pay", new_bill_payment_path(bill) %>` it's route passes bill_id

Comment: it must be ` <%= link_to "Pay", new_bill_payment_path(@bill) %>` then

Comment: Andrey thanks, I gave this a go and it didn't fix the problem. I may be fundamentally missing something. but the payments controller is nested under bill so the route '/bills/:bill_id/payments/new(.:format)' is sending bill_id. The payments new action picks up bill_id and builds @bill. if I remove the linked_to bits it all works fine. I've added the bill model, it may show some more detail.